# Javascript to display labels on the button with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's a simple question:

On the page there are two javascript.
The first script gets JSON and used it to build multiple forms with buttons:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.server.com/my/?callback=?",
    function(data){
        var results = [];
        $.each(data['results'], function(i, result) {
            results.push("<div class='accordion-group span4'><div class='accordion-heading'>Video Frame<blockquote><a href='http://server.com/video/?my=" + result.File + "' target='_blank'><img src='http://jpg.server.com/" + result.File + ".jpg' class='img-polaroid'/></a><p>" + result.ListId + "</p><small>" + result.OwnerId + "</small><small>" + result.updatedAt + "</small>    </blockquote><a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion2' href='#" + result.File + "'>Share video</a></div><div id='" + result.File + "' class='accordion-body collapse'><div class='accordion-inner'><form class='share_file_form'>Set list<input name='nd' id='user_id' type='hidden'><input name='file' value = '" + result.File + "' type='hidden'><div class='list'></div><input type='text' placeholder='New list'><div class='modal-footer'><button class='share_file_submit'>Share video</button></div></form><div id='user_info_result'></div></div></div></div>");
        });
        $('#mytile').html(results.join(""));
    }
);
```

The second script is a response by pressing a button on the form of constructing the first script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.server.com/set/",
                timeout: 20000,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".share_file_submit").attr("disabled", true);
                    $(".share_file_submit").html("Send <img src='http://src.server.com/loadr.gif' border='0'/>");
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
                    $("#share_file_submit").attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#share_file_submit").html("Share video");
                    $("#user_info_result_2").html(msg);
                },
                error: function(msg){
////////////////            $('#user_info_result_2').html("<div class='alert alert-error span3'>Failed from timeout. Please try again later. <span id='timer'></span> sec.</div>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works, but at the time of the second script, the inscription appears on the buttons of all forms, and I need only one button, which I click.

Comment: give your submit buttons unique ids rather than using a class

Comment: access the properties of button in this case can only be on behalf of a class

Comment: use 'this' then in the click function

Comment: 'this' is the element you click on try doing console.log(this) in the click function

Comment: dangerous to initalize validation plugin from submit button clcik...what if user hits Enter to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$(".share_file_submit").html("Send <img src='http://src.server.com/loadr.gif' border='0'/>");
```

It sets the html for all elements with the "share_file_submit" class on the entire page. You can fix it by adding a context to the selector:

```
$(".share_file_submit", $(form)).html("Send <img src='http://src.server.com/loadr.gif' border='0'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use validate plugin properly you shouldn't initialize it within a click handler.

Should be initializing right after the form building code.

Within `$.getJSON`

```
$('#mytile').html(results.join(""));
$('.share_file_form').validate(/* options*/);
```

The `submitHandler` will over ride the default `submit` event of the form and validation will be active while user fills out form.

To fix button issue:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {// form is current form elemnt

   $.ajax({
        beforeSend:function(){
             /* look within form for button*/
              $(form).find(".share_file_submit").prop('disabled',true);
          })
    });
```

Now if user uses `Enter` key you aren't relying on a click event to prevent submittal by browser default